# Custom header bar on Nokia S40 J2ME SDK 2.0

Tags: java-me, themes, lwuit

I'm trying to change the background and foreground/font color of the black/blue header bar in Nokia Asha.

[image]

I'm using the Nokia SDK 2.0 for Java and the Nokia Asha's LWUIT version. However, form.getTitleArea() and form.getTitleStyle() seem not to work as I'm not getting any changes when I use them to set the fgColor and the bgColor.

How can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard color in the title bar is defined by the color selected in the settings options of the device. You can't change it from code. If you need to create a custom header, you can  hide the default title bar and create some component which act like a header.

Comment: I thought that was the case only when I want to customize it and not just change the color. Rather weird! I'll have to re-implement all the header bar's functionality too.. Thank you for your answer.